# Upload 10 MB of data to Bigquery

Tags: google-apps-script, google-bigquery

I have CSV data of size 10 MB, So is it possible to upload 10 MB of data in bigquery at a time or it has some limitation.

Thanks & Regards,
Gopi Thakur

Answer (score 1):

In BigQuery you can load from file up to 5TB per file size (stored on GCS).

Scroll down until the examples are shown:
https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/loading-data-cloud-storage-csv

Answer (score 0):

Direct upload is Actually limited to a maximum of 10MB file size, as explained in [this](https://youtu.be/Abzj-Vyhi74?t=204) video at 3:24 from official google cloud channel.

But you can upload the file to cloud storage and then load your data to BigQuery from there, without any size limit.